# How do I add a separator using map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a const

```
const tags = [
  {
    tagName: "tag1",
    tagLink: "#"
  },
  {
    tagName: "tag2",
    tagLink: "#"
  },
  {
    tagName: "tag3",
    tagLink: "#"
  }
];
```

I want to use map function to render anchor tag and also I want a separator `|` in between the anchor tags.

I tried using join but then it doesn't work.

Please check the [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/71x97w97rx)

```
map using join
        <div style={style}>
          {tags
            .map((tag, i) => (
              <a href={tag.tagLink} alt="">
                {tag.tagName}
              </a>
            ))
            .join("|")}
        </div>
```

Produces: `[object Object]|[object Object]|[object Object]`

Comment: Please add the code in your fiddle to the question. You can use the snippet functionality to get it working here.

Comment: *"I tried to use join"* ... show us in the question then. We shouldn't have to go off site just to review your intial problem. Questions should be self contained. Off site demos are great but only as support for what actually exists in the question itself

Comment: It's in the fiddle brother @charlietfl

Comment: That's not the point..... what you tried that didn't work should be in **the question**. Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @charlietfl I have mentioned 3 ways I tried for my solution. It's in the fiddle link if you can open it once. Please stop roasting

Comment: @Andy it is react based. so I have provided my sandbox link in the question itself

Comment: Stop expecting people to go off site to review your problem! Questions should be self contianed and represent the issue right in the question as outlined in the [help]. That is the expected protocol. Stop being lazy

Comment: @charlietfl speak for yourself

Comment: Why so argumentative? People come here to help...not be insulted. All I have done is point out what is expected, yet all you want to do is argue about it. use the site properly and issues like this won't come up

Comment: @charlietfl sorry I didn't know you are on your.

Answer (score 8):

Could you render "|" in map function? 
Like I wrote in the comment, using join on JSX Object coerce it to String, which results in [object Object].

```
{tags.map((tag, i) => (
    <a href={tag.tagLink} alt="">
        {tag.tagName} {i < tags.length - 1 ? "|" : ""}
    </a>
))}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but your separator is inside anchor tag. Close enough. I was looking for something what @amulous answered below

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to use "join" elements of an array of elements. It will internally typecast the elements into a string which for any object comes as [object Object]. Hence, you are getting `[object Object]|[object Object]|[object Object]`

Something like this will work:

```
{tags.map((tag, i) => {
    return <span>
       <a href={tag.tagLink} alt="">
          {tag.tagName}
       </a> {i < tags.length - 1 ? "|" : null}
    </span>           
})}
```

Comment: @Rickie - Mark this as the solution if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can just map the array to create HTML tags.
The seperator can be added with a basic CSS class.

```js
const tags = [
  {
    tagName: "tag1",
    tagLink: "#first"
  },
  {
    tagName: "tag2",
    tagLink: "#second"
  },
  {
    tagName: "tag3",
    tagLink: "#third"
  }
];

const links = tags.map( tag => `<a href="${tag.tagLink}" id="${tag.tagName}">${tag.tagLink}</a>` );

document.querySelector( 'body' ).innerHTML = links.join( '' );
```

```css
a + a {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can render the links like others suggested

```
    const tags = [
  {
    tagName: "tag1",
    tagLink: "#first"
  },
  {
    tagName: "tag2",
    tagLink: "#second"
  },
  {
    tagName: "tag3",
    tagLink: "#third"
  }
];

const links = tags.map( tag => `<a href="${tag.tagLink}" class="divider" id="${tag.tagName}">${tag.tagLink}</a>` );

document.querySelector( 'body' ).innerHTML = links.join( '' );
```

and leave the separator to CSS, you can assign a class like this to your list of links :

```
.divider{
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xt09rpwm/

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite solution for this problem is to use flatMap

```
{tags.flatMap((tag, i) => [
  i > 0 && <span key={`divider-${i}}>|</span>,
  <a href={tag.tagLink} alt="" key={tag.tagName}>{tag.tagName}</a>,
])}
```

You can do it all in one function call, add keys to each element being rendered and also style the divider in anyway you want. (in this case I used a span, but you can use whatever fits the scenario)